# Why is matplotlib.animation slower with large windows that with small windows?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

So, I wrote up a Langton's Ant program.

```
#!/bin/env python
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import matplotlib.pyplot    as plt
import numpy                as np

w,h  = 100,100
d    = np.array([0,1])
p    = np.array([w//2,h//2])
grid = np.ones((w,h),dtype=int)

#MAIN

fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax   = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
img  = ax.imshow(grid,vmin=-1,vmax=1)
tle  = ax.text(0.5,0.95,"",bbox={'facecolor':'w','alpha':0.5,'pad':5},transform=ax.transAxes,ha="center")
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',bottom=False,top=False,labelbottom=False,labeltop=False)
ax.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',right=False,left=False,labelright=False,labelleft=False)

def langtons_ant_animator(frame):
    global w,h,d,p,grid
    v = grid[p[0],p[1]]
    grid[p[0],p[1]] = -v
    d = [[0,v],[-v,0]] @ d
    p = (p+d) % (w,h)
    img.set_data(grid)
    tle.set_text(f'{frame: 9} Steps; Point ({p[0]: 3},{p[1]: 3}), Direction ({d[0]: 2},{d[1]: 2})')
    return [tle,img]

animation = ani.FuncAnimation(
    fig      = fig,
    func     = langtons_ant_animator,
    interval = 1,
    blit     = True,
)

plt.show(block=True)
```

While this program is running I can dynamically change the window size. If I make the size really small (1in by 1in) the Ant moves at rapid speeds, nearing 1000 steps a second. But if I leave the window at (10in by 10in) it updates at around 100 or so steps a second. You would think that the number of pixels being updated is what effects the speed, but this isn't the case; change the window to a 1000,1000 and the animation runs just as fast at 10in by 10in.

1. It seems that window size is the most important factor in animation speed. Why?
2. Why doesn't img take into consideration the underlying numpy array size and know exactly the pixels that need to be updated together?
3. Could this be done smarter to get faster speeds?
4. Why are pixels so slow to update in matplotlib in the first place?